# Find out the maximum probability

Tags: probability, statistics

When 100 fair dices are thrown the probability of getting $n$ "6" can be modelled by

$$P=\binom{100}{n}\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^n\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{100-n}$$

What is the value of $n$ such that the probability is maximum?

I graphed the function and know the answer is $16$, but I am wondering why.

Comment: How does one find the maximum or minimum of any function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\displaystyle P_n=\binom{100}{n}\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^n$

Note that

\begin{align*}
&\quad\binom{100}{n}\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^n\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{100-n}>\binom{100}{n+1}\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^{n+1}\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{100-(n+1)}\\
\Longleftrightarrow &\quad \frac{100!}{n!(100-n)!}\times 5> \frac{100!}{(n+1)!(99-n)!}\\
\Longleftrightarrow &\quad \frac{5}{100-n}> \frac{1}{n+1}\\
\Longleftrightarrow &\quad n> \frac{95}{6}=15+\frac{5}{6}\\
\end{align*}

So $P_0\le P_1\le P_2\le\cdots\le P_{16}>P_{17}>P_{18}>\cdots>P_{100}$.

$P_n$ is the largest when $n=16$.

Comment: Why $P_0\le P_1\le P_2\le\cdots\le P_{16}$ ?

Comment: $P_{n}>P_{n+1} \Longleftrightarrow  n> \frac{95}{6}$ is equivalent $P_{n}\le P_{n+1} \Longleftrightarrow  n\le \frac{95}{6}$. Actually, as $\frac{95}{6}$ is not an integer, we can prove that $P_{n}< P_{n+1} \Longleftrightarrow  n< \frac{95}{6}$.

Answer (score 2):

What you are asking for is the **mode** of the binomial distribution.  The answer and proof is well-documented in the corresponding Wikipedia article:

[Wikipedia:  Binomial Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Mode)